# Replacement characters in file those don't equal to the pattern using sed

Tags: bash, unix

For example I have the file.in:

```
pattern
123
pattern
111
```

I could possibly replace characters in this file using sed:

```
sed 's/pattern/replacement/g' file.in  > file.out
```

file.out will be look like:

```
replacement
123
replacement
111
```

Is it possible to replace all the characters those do not equal to the pattern, like this:

```
pattern
replacement
pattern
replacement
```

Comment: An example for this exists in [sed one liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt): substitute "foo" with "bar" EXCEPT for lines which contain "baz"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 sed '/pattern/!s/.*/replacement/' file.in  > file.out
```

which replaces the entire line if pattern does not match.